# Image option is initialized when a graphic is in { }

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, options, rendering

It is helpful(necessary)to read the following before proceed:

[view is not fixed completely regardless of vewpoint](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204424/view-is-not-fixed-completely-regardless-of-vewpoint)

I found that, if a graphic code is surrounded by { }, the output becomes as if the code contain 'PreserveImageOptions->False'.

In detail, I think the four codes are practically identical.

1.
`{Graphics3D[Cuboid[], ViewPoint -> {1,1,1}]}`

2.
`{Graphics3D[Cuboid[], ViewPoint -> {1,1,1}, 
  PreserveImageOptions -> True]}`

3.
`{Graphics3D[Cuboid[], ViewPoint -> {1,1,1}, 
  PreserveImageOptions -> False]}`

4.
`{Graphics3D[Cuboid[], ViewPoint -> {1,1,1}, 
  PreserveImageOptions -> Automatic]}`

And 'the output of above four codes'

is equal to

'the output of the following code with surrounding { }'

`Graphics3D[Cuboid[], ViewPoint -> {1,1,1}, 
  PreserveImageOptions -> False]`

Now,

1) Am I thinking correctly?

2) Why previous image options are all ignored, when a graphic is in the curly bracket?

Comment: I do know that Mathematica has special rules for displaying images and graphics in `List` and `Grid`. For example, the automatic image size is adjusted for graphics in lists and grids. I don't know about how `PreserveImageOptions` and view point specifications are supposed to interact with these structures, though.